# Possible exception(s) thrown by CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(...)

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Which exception(s) can be raised by
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(...)`?

The C# metadata and [online documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn451621(v%3Dazure.100)) lists no exceptions for this method. Several examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere catch the base `Exception` class. Presumably only specific exceptions can be thrown. Quick-Starts and Tutorials on *learn.microsoft.com* don't include error handling.

Could it be just `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method can throw lots of exceptions like `ArgumentException`, `NotSupportedException`, or etc. However, if your inputs are correct, the most possible exceptions are `StorageException` for communications against Azure Storage service and `IOException` for reading the file from local disk.